# Регистры (теоретический вопрос)

Tags: ассемблер, память, асинхронность, процесс, теория

Здравствуйте, извиняюсь за возможно глупый вопрос, но скажите пожалуйста где располагаются регистры `eax, ebx, ecx, edx, edi, esi`, в оперативной памяти или процессоре?

Сам вопрос появился после того как я подумал, что если я не чего не путаю, то регистры всегда вроде-бы располагались в процессоре (ну если верить книжкам), но я не могу понять одного, как десятки процессов используют эти регистры грубо говоря асинхронно, процессор же не может разорваться на каждый процесс. Ну и вот с этого момента мне стало очень интересно как так может быть и я решил спросить у профессионалов.

Comment: в процессоре. у каждого ядра свой набор регистров. на одном ядре одновременно выполняется только один поток команд (процесс). Время от времени ОС передает управление от одного процесса к другому, сохраняя текущие значения регистров в TSS

Comment: @Mike ну вот смотрите, допустим у меня 2 ядра, у меня запущен например фильм в VLC Player (первый процесс), на фоне играет музыка в Браузере (второй процесс), ещё у меня торрент например качает игру (третий процесс) и под конец ещё я с кем нибудь одновременно говорю по Skype (четвёртый процесс), так вот и как работают эти 4 процесса если ядра 2, а по ядру по процессу?

Comment: а всё увидел, вы просто обновили свой комент )

Comment: @Mike добавьте ответ, а я его отмечу

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy, *как работают эти 4 процесса* -- боюсь вас расстраивать, но на самом деле **намного** больше 4 :) Посмотрите в диспетчер задач (если Windows) или в вывод `ps` (если Linux)...

Comment: @PinkTux да это я привёл пример, у меня у самого вот сейчас в фоне 98 процессов висит, так что вы тут меня "не удивляйте" :)))

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy, это вы меня удивляете: материалов на эту тему навалом, репутации у вас под 3 тыщи...

Comment: @PinkTux типа 3 тысячи для рейтинга это дофигища? ))

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy, нет, я просто задумываюсь о вечном. Как рейтинг связан с тем, что человек не знает азов?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

регистры располагаются, конечно, в процессоре (если речь о современных распространённых процессорах).

попеременно же используются они разными процессами благодаря механизму [многозадачности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C).

---

в грубом приближении:

внутри процессора есть таймер, который время от времени посылает процессору сигнал («прерывание»), при получении которого процессор сохраняет текущее содержимое всех регистров в стек (находится в оперативной памяти, обычно каждый процесс имеет собственный стек; а сохраняются туда регистры не только с данными, но и со всякой контрольно-управляющей информацией, типа *ip — instruction pointer* — адресом следующей выполняемой команды) и передаёт управление по адресу обработчика данного прервывания (обработчик обычно реализован в ядре операционой системы).

обработчик выбирает, какой процесс следует запустить следующим ([какому процессу отдать очередной «квант времени»](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0)), и даёт процессору команду «загрузить в регистры то, что сохранённо там-то».

восстановленный же из стека процесс продолжает работу «как ни в чём не бывало», до следующего срабатывания таймера.

Answer (score 1):

Регистры в процессоре. Многозадачность - фича ОС, которая сохраняет контекст процесса, включая регистры. Так и получается что один набор регистров вполне досаточен для многих процессов.